# The Default Freezer (iOS)

Tags: ios, kernel, virtual-memory, mach, xnu

Levin had a chapter in his book [Mac OS X and iOS internals: To the Apple's Core.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118057651) related to The Default Freezer which can be used in Virtual Memory Management.  It is stated that it is implemented in `osfmk/vm/default_freezer.c`

At the time of writing this was still incomplete. Does anyone know if this is implemented in newer versions of iOS?  I did not find a lot of documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is, in iOS 8, in conjunction with memorystatus/jetsam. It'll be covered in more detail in the 2nd Edition of his book, too.